# Inner binder class for service: static or not?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service with an inner binder class:

```
public class MyService extends Service{

private final ServiceB binder = new ServiceB();

   @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return binder;
}

  //inner binder class
  class NewsServiceB extends Binder{
         .... 
  }
```

my question is: is this pattern ok?Or I should make the binder class static, maybe with a WeakReference to service?Mind that **EVERY** binder method make use of service's methods, so making it non static is very useful as code is cleaner and more immediate.

I fear memory leaks, neverthless no warnings show...

Comment: The pattern looks fine to me. Why do you fear memory leaks?

Comment: Well...my service takes 9MB of ram and it seems too much to me...